# Link sharing vs direct access to prevent inheritence rules

Tags: sharepoint-online, inheritance, sharing

We have created a doc library with following folder structure:

Company name / department / sub department

At the sub department level we have given users read permission to the folder via the advanced settings.

When sharing, we have unchecked the setting highlighted below:

[image]

Now when I add user at the department level (via advanced settings using the same setting as above - that is - uncheck the highlighted setting) then the user cannot see the sub department folder.

Is this behaviour because adding permission at sub department level breaks inheritence.

What is the way to get around this?

1. Is it to check mark that setting when sharing? Which technically means do not follow inheritence rules and have access to everything below.
2. Or should I use link sharing which also seems to behave the same - that is - inheritence doesn't apply and has access to everything below.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the files in your subdepartment folder have unique permission, so your sharing doesn't work.

To get around this, you can checkmark the setting when sharing, which technically means do not follow inheritance rules and have access to everything below.